# minikube status Unknown, Windows 10, docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-10, minikube

I was trying to see the dashboard, previously works fine...

Now I get using minikube dashboard

```
λ minikube dashboard

X Exiting due to GUEST_STATUS: state: unknown state "minikube": docker container inspect minikube --format=: exit status 1
stdout:


stderr:
Error: No such container: minikube

*
╭──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                                                  │
│    * If the above advice does not help, please let us know:                                                      │
│      https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose                                                    │
│                                                                                                                  │
│    * Please attach the following file to the GitHub issue:                                                       │
│    * - C:\Users\JOSELU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\minikube_dashboard_dc37e18dac9641f7847258501d0e823fdfb0604c_0.log    │
│                                                                                                                  │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

With `minikube status`

```
λ minikube status
E0604 13:13:20.260421   27600 status.go:258] status error: host: state: unknown state "minikube": docker container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}: exit status 1
stdout:


stderr:
Error: No such container: minikube
E0604 13:13:20.261425   27600 status.go:261] The "minikube" host does not exist!
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Nonexistent
kubelet: Nonexistent
apiserver: Nonexistent
kubeconfig: Nonexistent
```

With the command `minikube profile list`

```
λ minikube profile list
|----------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|
| Profile  | VM Driver | Runtime |      IP      | Port | Version | Status  | Nodes |
|----------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|
| minikube | docker    | docker  | 192.168.49.2 | 8443 | v1.20.2 | Unknown |     1 |
|----------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|
```

Now,...

**What would be it happens?**

**What would be the best solution?**

Thansk...

Answer (score 1):

**Remove unused data:**
docker system prune

**Clear minikube's local state:**
minikube delete

**Start the cluster:**
minikube start --driver=<driver_name>
(In your case driver name is docker as per minikube profile list info shared by you)

**Check the cluster status:**
minikube status

**Use the following documentation for more information:**
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/#examples
https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/